# Prove that group $G$ is abelian when $K$ field has only 2 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $G$ is a group. $G=\{(g,a) : g\in K, a \in K^*\mid (g,a)(h,b)=(g+ah,ab)\}$

$K^*$ means $K$ without ${0}$.

Proove that $G$ is Abelian $\Leftrightarrow$ $K$ has only 2 elements.

$$(g,a)(h,b) = (h,b)(g,a)$$

$$(g+ah,ab)=(h+bg,ab)$$

Could you give me some tips?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. $h$ is $\equiv$ to $g$ and $b$ to $a$

Comment: This is still unclear.  The notation $G=\{(g,a) : g\in K, a \in K^*\mid (g,a)(h,b)=(g+ah,ab)\}$ should mean that $G$ is the set of all ordered pairs for which the condition $(g,a)(h,b)=(g+ah,ab)$ holds, and that has me wondering if the juxtaposition of ordered pairs means term-by-term multiplication.  But that doesn't make sense, so I surmise that you intended the equality $(g,a)(h,b)=(g+ah,ab)$ to define the group operation. This is certainly not standard language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you mean that $G$ is defined as
$$
G=\{(x,a):x\in K, a\in K^*\}
$$
with operation
$$
(x,a)(y,b)=(x+ay,ab)
$$

If $K$ has just two elements, then the group is isomorphic to $(K,+)$, so it's abelian.

If $G$ is abelian, then you must have
$$
(x+ay,ab)=(y+bx,ba)
$$
for all $x,y\in K$ and $a,b\in K^*$ which means
$$
x+ay=y+bx
$$
or
$$
x(1-b)=y(1-a)
$$
If $x=0$ and $y=1$, this means $1-a=0$ for all $a\in K^*$.

Comment: Hmm. You see I've done it so far to point $x(1−b)=y(1−a)$ but I wasnt clever enough to inerpret this result. I got stuck there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user187978 The key is *for all*, which means you can use whatever element of $K$ you like. But the only elements you really know are $0$ and $1$, so… `;-)`